# Using yield won't generate new numbers (Using next function)

Tags: python, yield-from

I am trying to use yield to generate new numbers on each iteration as shown below:

```
def nextSquare():
    i = 1
  
    # An Infinite loop to generate squares 
    while True:
        yield i*i                
        i += 1  # Next execution resumes 
                # from this point
```

When I try:

```
>>> for num in nextSquare():
    if num > 100:
         break    
    print(num)
```

I get the desired output:

```
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
```

but when I try:
`next(nextSquare())`

it always yields the same old result. Am I doing something wrong? Instead of generating new numbers in a for loop I am interested in generating on demand.

Comment: Every time you _call_ nextSquare, you get a fresh iterator. If you want to get multiple values from the same iterator, use e.g. `square = nextSquare()` once then `next(square)` multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, calling nextSquare everytime generates a fresh iterator and so I changed my code to:

```
gen = nextSquare()
```

and onDemand calling of `next(gen)` yields expected result.